# Relating height to length in a root system

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-groups, root-systems, coxeter-groups, reductive-groups

I have a question about a proposition from Casselman's [notes](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/p-adic-book.pdf) on representation theory.  Let $\mathfrak a$ be a finite dimensional vector space, and $\Sigma$ a reduced root system in the dual $\mathfrak a^{\ast}$ with Weyl group $W$ and base $\Delta$.  Via the inverse transpose, $W$ is also a group of automorphisms of $\mathfrak a$.

For $\theta \subseteq \Delta$, let $\mathfrak a_{\theta} = \{ x \in \mathfrak a : \langle x,\alpha \rangle = 0 \textrm{ for all } \alpha \in \theta \}$.  In this vector space we have the hyperplanes $\mathfrak a_{\theta} \cap \mathfrak a_{\alpha} = \{ x \in \mathfrak a_{\theta} : \langle x ,\alpha \rangle = 0\}$ for $\alpha \in \Sigma^+ - [\theta]$, which partition $\mathfrak a_{\theta}$ into facets.  The facets of maximal dimension are called chambers, the facets of next maximal dimension are called faces etc. (the usual notation from Bourbaki *Lie Groups and Lie Algebras* chapter V).

The set $C_{\theta} = \{x \in \mathfrak a_{\theta} : \langle x,\alpha \rangle > 0 \textrm{ for all } \alpha \in \Delta - \theta \}$ is a chamber in $\mathfrak a_{\theta}$.  It is proved (Proposition 1.2.2) that every other chamber in $\mathfrak a_{\theta}$ is equal to $w C_{\theta'}$ for a unique $\theta' \subseteq \Delta$ and $w \in W$ with $w(\theta') = \theta$.

Let $W(\theta,\theta') = \{ w \in W : w(\theta') = \theta\}$ (confusing notation I know).  For $w \in W(\theta,\theta')$, the *height* of $w$ (with respect to $\theta'$) is the minimal gallery length from the chamber $wC_{\theta'}$ to $C_{\theta}$.  As usual, a gallery is a collection of chambers, each sharing a face with the next.

The proposition I want to understand is this:

[image]

I don't know where to start with this because I do not know how to begin relating height to length.  The only useful result I can think of is that for an *elementary conjugation*, i.e. a Weyl group element of the form $w_0 = w_{l,\Omega}w_{l,\theta}$ for $\Omega = \theta \cup \{\alpha\}$, we have $\ell(w_0w) = \ell(w_0) + \ell(w)$ for all $w \in W_{\theta}$ (Lemma 1.1.2).